# CSS to mark up text to look like the sample provided?

Tags: css

I have seen css that can make text look like an image in the past. I am not a front end developer so my CSS is very rusty...

I am trying to use a DIV tag and markup the text in each div tag to look like the image samples below. notice there is a space between each letter.

if there is a WHYSIWYG CSS editor online that allows for this type of formatting that would be a great resource to have.

EDIT: The hardest part for me is getting a blue square around the first letter!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I have done this using first-ltter psuedo element [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vs2N/3/). W3Schools on this element [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-letter.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Very quickly, something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/eW532/

EDIT: Misread...You're talking about the spacing.

EDIT again: http://jsfiddle.net/eW532/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the CSS letter-spacing property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp

Answer (score 0):

you could use the css rule: `letter-spacing: 1px;` or something, there are more in-depth solutions that require different languages though.