# css targeting specific div tags in a large HTML web page

Tags: css

In relation to my previous [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924177/css-to-mark-up-text-to-look-like-the-sample-provided).
If I am using the below HTML code as part of my web page, where there will likely be many more div tags, how can I target these particular divs in my CSS ? The sample I think works best is [This Answer][2].

I added Id attributes to make the divs more selectable in a large HTML DOM... I don't know how else to make them more distinguishable. If there is a better method for doing so please let me know. The goal is to apply the CSS design to about 6 div tag elements inside a large share point portal website. If there is a more generic way that would be cool so I can easily add more sections and use this format in the future... I can add a class attribute to each element I want the formatting applied to, but I don't know the syntax.

What's the designer professional web way of getting this done?

```
<div id="projectName">
       Realtime Account Activiation
</div>

<div id="divAnnounce">
        Announcements
</div>
```

I have
http://jsfiddle.net/eW532/1/

I am using the code below but getting bad results where the entire horizontal length is blue but not the first letter. I'm trying to have an html element use two classes together.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .even_spacing {  color: purple;
                        background-color: #d8da3d }

        .first_letter {  background:blue;
                        color:white;
                        padding:4px 0px 4px 5px;}           
  </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="first_letter even_spacing">
        Realtime Account Activiation
    </div>

    <div class="first_letter even_spacing">
        Announcements
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in the HTML file put
`<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Path/to/your/stylesheet.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>` at the top of the page to reference the new style sheet.

in your CSS File put:

```
#projectName{
style:value;
}

#divAnnounce{

}
```

The # targets things with ID's if you use a . before it will target the class names,

You can also use both if you need to get specific such as

```
#idname.classname{

}
```

If you have another div inside of the divAnnounce you can do

```
#divAnnounce #yournewdiv{

}
```

OR

```
#divAnnounce div{

}
```

OR

```
#newdivid{

}
```

Notice the space inbetween the two targets saying that they are a parent and child

Comment: The remark for a div inside of the divAnnounce has a superfluous instruction. As ID's in HTML must always be unique one can suffice with adding just #yournewdiv {} to your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
.class1 {
style: value;
}

.class2 {
style:value;
}
</style>

<div class="class1" id="projectName">
       Realtime Account Activiation
</div>

<div class="class2" id="divAnnounce">
        Announcements
</div>
```

More info: [Class vs ID selectors](http://ulyssesonline.com/2007/10/12/css-class-vs-id/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.className` notations for classes and `#IDName` notations for ID's:

```
.className {
style:value;
}

#IDName {
style:value;
}
```

```
<div class="className">Test</div>

<div id="IDName">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CSS classes](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/class.php) and [selectors](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer about similar issue.

[Load an external CSS for a specific DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379168/load-an-external-css-for-a-specific-div/18252363#18252363)

I believe this should help you.

Make sure to verify that the CSS file will always return "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the response header for loading external files.

If you load CSS data using some other way you can just use the `applyCSSToHTML()` function.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question and looking at the code on jsfiddle I suspect that you want to make the first letter of your text pop out with a different style than the rest of the text.
The best way to go about this is to make use of a CSS pseudo-element called `::first-letter`. So your HTML page would look like this:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .even_spacing {
        color: purple;
        background-color: #d8da3d;
        display: block;
      }
      .even_spacing::first-letter {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 4px 0px 4px 5px;
      }           
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div class="even_spacing">
        Realtime Account Activiation
      </div>
      <div class="even_spacing">
        Announcements
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My advice is to use an unordered list (`<ul>`) instead of divisions (`<div>`) because you are creating a list of actionable items.
So this would look like:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .even_spacing {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .even_spacing li {
        color: purple;
        background-color: #d8da3d;
      }
      .even_spacing li::first-letter {
        color:white;
        background-color:blue;
        padding:4px 0px 4px 5px;
      }           
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <ul class="even_spacing">
        <li>Realtime Account Activiation</li>
        <li>Announcements</li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

REMARK: Please be aware that this pseudo-element (just like `::first-line`) is only to be used in block type elements (like `<div>` or `<p>`), not in inline elements (like `<span>`). As a rule, double colons (::) should be used instead of a single colon (:). This distinguishes pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements.

For more information about this pseudo-element see the [::first-letter MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)